# Why do we, at times, follow colon by consecutive full stops?

Tags: punctuation, lists, periods

Let me reproduce a text:

> I have three answers:
>
> 1. M is N.
> 2. N is O.
> 3. O is P.

In the above text, three answers that follow are parts of the same sentence. This is evident from ":" (colon) used in the first part of the sentence. If so, then how does each of the three answers that follow the first part of the sentence take a  "." (full stop)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, you have an enumerated list, in tabular form, where each entry is a full sentence (**independent clause**), hence the "."(period).  The list is introduced by the ":"(**colon**) denoting ***note hereafter***. Your list could also be written as:

> I have three answers: M is N; N is O; and O is P.
>   I have three answers: 1) M is N; 2) N is O; and 3) O is P.

where a ";"(**semicolon**) is used to separate each list entry since they are **independent clauses**.